# Unity UnityWebRequest is not returning a value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest, coroutine, ienumerator

I have some code to get some data from a database. To use in my game. 
I have setup an coroutine to get this data with the WWW framework in unity. 
But when i run my code the data is never logged in my yield return function. Why is this happening? See the code below for the points that are not working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("run ma routine");
        StartCoroutine(GetText("http://localhost/artez/praktijk_opdracht/interface_v4/app/php/get_fashion.php", (result) =>{
            Debug.Log(result); // this log function is never logging a value.. Why is this?
        }));
    }

    void Update () 
    {
    }

    IEnumerator GetText(string url, Action<string> result) {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.data); // this log is returning the requested data. 
        }
    }
}
```

What i want is the `StartCoroutine()` to log the data not the `debug.log` inside of the `IEnumerator()`

If something needs more explanation i am happy to provide that.

Comment: `WWW` is not a Framework. It's a variable name you gave to a `UnityWebRequest` object.

Comment: @Franck There also [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) which is use to o the-same thing. `UnityWebRequest` is the newest API to make requests in Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invoke the result `Action` after the `UnityWebRequest`  request is done inside the `GetText` function:

```
if (result != null)
    result(www.downloadHandler.text);
```

The new `GetText` function:

```
IEnumerator GetText(string url, Action<string> result)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
        if (result != null)
            result(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.data); // this log is returning the requested data. 
        if (result != null)
            result(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah i see, but what exactly does the `yield return` then in this case?

Comment: `yield return www.SendWebRequest()` sends the request you made then waits until the result is done. The `result(www.downloadHandler.text);` puts the result from the request to the `Action` parameter so that you can access it where you called the function with `StartCoroutine`